# Update from 2.5.28 to 3.5.1 then to 3.6 on PHP 5.6 everything works except joomla update or database fix cause these errors

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, joomla-2.5

clicking joomla update button in backend end gives this error:

> 1054 Unknown column 'a.extra_query' in 'field list'
>
> SQL=
>
> ```
> SELECT DISTINCT a.update_site_id, a.type, a.location, a.last_check_timestamp, a.extra_query`
> FROM `#__update_sites` AS `a`
> INNER JOIN #__update_sites_extensions AS b ON a.update_site_id = b.update_site_id
> WHERE a.enabled = 1 AND b.extension_id = 700
> ```

clicking to fix the 28 errors listed on database button results in this error:

> 1054 Unknown column 'title_alias' in '#__content'
>
> SQL=
>
> ```
> ALTER TABLE `#__content`
> CHANGE `title_alias` `title_alias` VARCHAR( 255 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '';
> ```

Answer (score 3):

You have an inconsistent database state.

Joomla! is trying to run the instructions in

```
administrator/components/com_admin/sql/updates/mysql/3.0.0.sql
```

which are designed to update your database structure from 2.5.28 to 3.0.0, and it's trying to drop a column that is not there: most likely, the script was run already and didn't complete for some reason.

You might try to understand what went wrong from the log/install errors, but you'd still have to fix your database structure manually. This is very painful, takes hours, and any human error might compromise the result.

**The fast and easy way: modify the script to add error tolerance.**

**Warning**: while I have already done this previously, this is not an officially approved method and is inherently dangerous. Make a db backup first, and keep it until you have confirmed everything works as expected.

**The SQL `IGNORE` keyword.**
Simple as that. **Edit your 3.0.0.sql file**

1. insert IGNORE as follows:

   - `ALTER TABLE   =>   ALTER IGNORE TABLE`
   - `UPDATE        =>   UPDATE IGNORE`
   - `INSERT        =>   INSERT IGNORE`
2. based on your current database content, you might find duplicates that are safe to delete at the end of the following tables:

   - `#__extensions` (the templates isis, protostar, beez3 may be duplicated)
   - `#__template_styles` (the styles for the templates isis, protostar, beez3 may be duplicated)

Good luck! If it fails, check the new errors you get, and comment here we might need to fix some other issues.

Comment: @Marc did this answer solve your question?  Do you know how to accept an answer? Please progress this page to a system-recognized resolution.